# Keep track of latitude/longitude distances between users

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app that keeps continuous track of how close users are to each other. I am able to get latitude and longitude measurements but need some advice on how to keep track of everyone and how far they are from each other.

I would prefer not to have to use the haversine formula on every coordinate against every other coordinate every time.

NOT USING GOOGLE MAPS OPTIONS- NEED TO FORMULATE AN IN HOUSE SOLUTION.

Comment: just find distance in terms of gps location i.e. lat long. That would be rough measurements for distance.

Comment: GeoFire should work for you as expected with some workaround: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/08/geofire-goes-mobile.html